# Error while saving data in text file

Tags: arduino-mega, sd-card, rtc

I created a function that saves the timestamp in a text file, but it saves unreadable. Full of invalid characters, example: **Ÿ@Â   O   ƒº!¥ Ÿ@Â   O   ƒº!¥ Ÿ@Â   O   ƒº!¥ Ÿ**

```
#include <Wire.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <SD.h>
#include "RTClib.h"

RTC_Millis rtc;
File txt;
const char * getCurrentTimestamp()
{
    char dateBuffer[40];
    DateTime now = rtc.now();
    sprintf(dateBuffer,"%02u-%02u-%04u %02u:%02u:%02u", now.day(), now.month(), now.year(), now.hour(), now.minute(), now.second());
    return dateBuffer;
}

void saveLog()
{
  txt = SD.open("dados.txt", FILE_WRITE);
  txt.print(getCurrentTimestamp());
  txt.close();
}

void setup() {
  pinMode(53, OUTPUT);
  SD.begin(4); 
  Serial.begin(9600);
  rtc.begin(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println(getCurrentTimestamp());
  saveLog();
  delay(1000);
}
```

My code is very simple, do not understand where I went wrong. if I copy the following code snippet for **saveData()** function and save the **dateBuffer** variable, everything works normally.

```
char dateBuffer[40];
DateTime now = rtc.now();
sprintf(dateBuffer,"%02u-%02u-%04u %02u:%02u:%02u", now.day(), now.month(), now.year(), now.hour(), now.minute(), now.second());
```

how to save the timestamp correctly in the file through the function **getCurrentTimestamp()** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function, `getCurrentTimestamp()` saves the date string in an automatic variable - it is on the function's stack frame which gets freed as soon as that function returns. Either `Serial.println()` or `savelog()` is overwriting it.

The proper way to do what you're trying to do is to make the buffer live for the duration of both function calls. One way is to use a global buffer. Another is to declare the buffer in `loop()` and pass it to both functions.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know you should use

```
text.write(getCurrentTime());
```

That because (if I'm not wrong) you need to send it as ASCII characters so the text editor will be able to read them in the right way.